# Intersection of the null space of a matrix with integer vectors

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, projection-matrices, smith-normal-form

I have an $m\times n$ rational matrix $A$ which is full rank and has linearly independent columns. With $m>n$ I would like to find all integer values of $x$ for which

$$A\vec x=0$$

If $A$ was an integer matrix this could be calculated by using the Smith normal form to solve [linear Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation). However, since $A$ has rational elements the solutions to $\vec x$ can also be rational. I would like to find a general form of the allowed values of $\vec x$ which are integers.

I would expect to be able to find some form like

$$\vec x=S\vec k$$

where $\vec k$ is a $n$-vector consisting of any choice of integers. My first guess is that

$$S=A^+(I-AA^+)$$

where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse such that $A^+A=I$ and $(I-AA^+)$ is a projection onto the null space of $A$.

This would mean
$$A\vec x=AA^+(I-AA^+)\vec k=(AA^+-AA^+AA^+)\vec k=(AA^+-AA^+)\vec k=0$$

But this  would also mean

$$\vec x=S\vec k=(A^+-A^+AA^+)\vec k =(A^+-A^+)\vec k=0$$

Does this problem have a solution in general or for specific cases of $A$?

Comment: What does it mean, "not full rank but has linearly independent columns. "?

Comment: Sorry, it should say is full rank and has lineally independent columns. It just has more rows than columns

Comment: you can always re-scale $A$ by an integer to make it an integer matrix since its components are rational.  You just stated A " has linearly independent columns" so the nullspace only contains the zero vector.